# Tracking Outlook emails

Tags: nodemailer, outlook-restapi

How can I track my outlook emails using nodejs application like It should give staats on delivered read and replied how can i do this for me reading the replied email from same thread is difficult to implement can anyone help me on this?

IMAP POP3 and Authentication is done